# Numerical errors due to terms of the form $\frac{1}{r}$ (r goes to 0 at the boundary) while using finite difference method

Tags: finite-difference, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations using finite difference method.

There are few terms of the form $\frac{A(r)}{r}$, both $A(r)$ and r go to zero at the boundary. Analytically this term is well defined but numerically these terms are leading to error which very quickly break the simulation.

I am using leapfrog method if that matters. I read somewhere that leapfrog method has dissipation inbuilt so it should be stable, but it's clearly not the case.

Any advice on how to proceed?
Should I change my algorithm? Or use higher order schemes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999199963829

Comment: The basic advice is to consider the new variable $v(r) = A(r)/r$. One does that in the solution of the Schrödinger equation for atomic systems, for example.

Comment: Do you know the limit $$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{A(r)} {r}$$, it's pretty important in this case. If the limit is a finite constant, then there is a lot of methods like in the paper linked by Spencer. If the limit is infinity, then there's a problem